# PostgreSQL sorting with Cyrillic "ь"

Tags: postgresql, sorting, postgresql-9.3, cyrillic

Just take a look, please:

```
WITH toks AS (
  SELECT tok
    FROM
      unnest('{ь, а, чь, ча, чль, чла}'::text[]) AS tok
  ORDER BY tok COLLATE "uk_UA"
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS "#", tok FROM toks
ORDER BY tok COLLATE "uk_UA"
```

PostgreSQL 9.3 (ubuntu) gives me this result:

```
 # | tok 
---+-----
 1 | а
 2 | ча
 3 | чль
 4 | чла
 5 | чь
 6 | ь
(6 rows)
```

Here rows 1, 2, 5 and 6 are sorted properly ("ь" goes after "а") while rows 3 and 4 are sorted wrongly ("а" goes after "ь").

All letters are Cyrillic, I've checked so many times.

Please, what's wrong and how to workaround .(

**UPDATE**: this is a bug which was fixed in mainstream recently: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17293

**UPDATE2**: Please note my own answer below.

Comment: What is the encoding of your database? Seems that it matters...

Comment: @TagirValeev Encoding: UTF8, Collation: uk_UA.UTF-8 (both as shown by pgadmin3).

Comment: PostgreSQL uses the order of the locale from the operating system. If you use the command-line `sort` utility with the same collation and the same data, that should output the same order.

Comment: @DanielVérité yes, `sort` gives somewhat different but wrong result also: `ь > а` but `ть < та`. So, there is somewhere an issue with system's locale?

Comment: @DanielVérité no, if I `export LANG=uk_UA` --- `sort`ing seems to be ok; there is a problem with default `LANG=uk_UA.UTF-8`.

Comment: But then what is the encoding? Maybe it's sorting an UTF-8 file with KOI8-U rules, which may sort as intended by happenstance.

Comment: What operating system and version?

Comment: @CraigRinger it looks like this bug was fixed 2015-05-26: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solutions has been completed in these steps:

1. Searched the Internet and http://linux.org.ua/ for any information; found http://linux.org.ua/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.pl?num=1407783417/6#6
2. Starred at bug report: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17293, fixed 2015-05-26
3. Checked `glibc` version (2.19 now)
4. Grabbed a patch; edited the patch (removed the section for `Makefile`)
5. Backed `/usr/share/i18n/locales/uk_UA` up
6. Patched it with `[cd /usr/share/i18n/;] patch --dry-run -p2 < locales_uk_UA_softsign.diff` --- then with no `--dry-run`.
7. `locale-gen`
8. `service postgresql restart`

Answer (score 7):

PostgreSQL relies on the operating system's locale to sort.

See how Ubuntu 14.04 sorts that list:

```
# locale-gen uk_UA.UTF-8
Generating locales...
  uk_UA.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

# cat >file
ь
а
чь
ча
чль
чла

# LC_ALL=uk_UA.UTF-8 sort file
а
ча
чль
чла
чь
ь
```

In the comments you say it's different but what I get here is exactly the same order as your query.

Indeed `чль` comes before `чла` which intuitively is weird but I don't know cyrillic.

You may look at `/usr/share/i18n/locales/uk_UA` for the definition of the locale, and bring it up as an ubuntu bug of the `locales` packages.

Comment: Thank you, indeed: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17293. I will check everything.